# Save the image to internal storage, obtain and open it in the gallery app

Tags: java, android, image, android-gallery, android-internal-storage

I want to save an image in the **internal memory** of the phone and then open it in the default image viewer. The gallery opens with a black screen. Reviewing the picture on the Android Device Monitor, is in the following path: "/data/data/com.myapp.myappname/app_ImageTest/test.jpg" transfer it to the computer and the image opens properly.

This is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.test);
    path_absolute = saveToInternalStorage(bitmap);
}


public void open_photo(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("file://" + path_absolute );
    intent.setDataAndType(uri,"image/*");
    startActivity(intent);
}

private String saveToInternalStorage(Bitmap bitmapImage){
    ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
    File directory = cw.getDir("ImageTest", Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    File mypath=new File(directory,"test.jpg");

    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(mypath);
        bitmapImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            fos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return directory.getAbsolutePath();
}
```

Would welcome a detailed explanation, I'm newbies on Android. Thank you!

Comment: from where this image came from?

Comment: The image comes from drawable.